# Import user passwords

Tags: craft3, users, plugin-feedme

I'm using Feedme to import users from one Craft site to another via an XML feed. I'd like to include users passwords too. I thought that `{{ user.password|hash }}` would do the trick but when I test this out after import using one of the imported accounts I get the "Invalid email or password" error msg. I know the account has ported across, email address 
is correct, and it's live. So must be something with the password. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `user.password` should already be the hashed password... have you tried just that?

Comment: Hey Brad. I just sent existing users (there weren't many) a link to reset their passwords for the new system, so no dramas. I'll keep in mind for next time though.

Comment: Fair enough... should we close this question, then?